# ORACLE FUNCTION testcase

Tags: oracle, function, plsql, exception

I want to create a function which returns BOOLEAN.
The function would check if a value exists (classic verification if a department already exists).

I implemented the NO_DATA_FOUND exception and I want, also, to add the WHEN OTHERS; but I don't have in  mind any test case.

Here  is  the code of the function:

```
FUNCTION fnc_department_exists(p_dept_name  hr.departments.department_name%TYPE) RETURN BOOLEAN IS
    v_dummy   PLS_INTEGER;
BEGIN
    -- Verifica existenta unui anumit departament
    pkg_logging.prc_log('HR', 'VERIFIC', 'Verifica daca exista departamentul "' || p_dept_name || '"');
    SELECT  1 
    INTO    v_dummy
    FROM    hr.departments
    WHERE   UPPER(department_name) = UPPER(p_dept_name);

    pkg_logging.prc_log('HR', 'VERIFIC', 'Departamentul "' || p_dept_name || '" exista');

    RETURN TRUE;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
        pkg_logging.prc_log('HR', 'VERIFIC', 'Departamentul "' || p_dept_name || '" nu exista');
        RETURN FALSE;
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        pkg_logging.prc_log('HR', 'VERIFIC', 'A aparut o alta eroare: ' || SQLCODE || ' - ' || SQLERRM);
        RETURN FALSE;
END fnc_department_exists;
```

Can someone suggest a test case for WHEN OTHERS branch, please?

Thank you,

Comment: There could always be some system error such as a corrupt index block, in which case you'd probably want things to start failing naturally rather than reporting the department doesn't exist. Also if you get a chance to refactor your logging package, you could have it pick up `sqlerrm` itself and capture it in a separate column without the need for developers to concatenate it with the application error message. And `sqlcode` isn't giving you any useful information here - I would remove it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a department named e.g. `'PAYROLL'`, add another one named `'Payroll'` and another one named `'payroll'`. This will cause the SELECT to fail with an ORA-01422 (TOO_MANY_ROWS) exception.

I suggest that when your code gets into the `WHEN OTHERS` block, you should re-raise the exception rather than eating it and returning false. Thus:

```
WHEN OTHERS THEN
  pkg_logging.prc_log('HR', 'VERIFIC', 'A aparut o alta eroare: ' ||
                      SQLCODE || ' - ' || SQLERRM);
  RAISE;
```

Best of luck.

Comment: The condition `WHERE   UPPER(department_name) = UPPER(p_dept_name);` prevent any upper/lower case combination resulting in same value multiple times.

Comment: There's no GROUP BY clause or anything to limit it from returning multiple rows; thus, if you have three rows in your table with DEPARTMENT_NAME values of 'PAYROLL', 'Payroll', and 'payroll', the query will return three rows, and the use of `UPPER` will ensure that `UPPER('PAYROLL') = UPPER('Payroll') = UPPER('payroll')`. For example [see this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7f616/2)

Comment: I shall start from an empty table and start inserting into it, firstly checking if the department name already exists.

If the table is empty, 1st insert will work just fine but the second will fail as the dequired department already exists into the table.